# Can we change the diaplsy format of data from one kendo component to other on runtime in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-grid, kendo-listview

I have a page with two buttons in header. I need to display same data on click of both buttons resp. but in different layout, means at click of first button i want to display a kendo asp.net mvc grid and at click of second i want tot display that data in a form of listview. So the question is, is it possible to display the data initially as a grid or listview (any one ) and at runtime we can change the format from grid to listview so that we don't have to create seperate controls partial views for that. Or any better idea on how to implement it is also welcomed.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far or post the code here ?

Comment: No i have not done anything related to that..I was searching on web and didn't found any solution, so just wanted to clarify whether it's possible or not.